# OpenSSL - find error depth in certificate chain

Tags: c, ssl, openssl

I am writing a C program to retrieve and verify an x509 certificate chain using OpenSSL. This is my first time programming in C and am relying heavily on the tutorial at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-openssl/

I am able to retrieve any error code from the connection using the code below:

```
if (SSL_get_verify_result(ssl) != X509_V_OK)
{
    printf("\nError verifying certificate\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "Error Code: %lu\n", SSL_get_verify_result(ssl));
}
```

however I also need to know which certificate is the offending one. Is there are way to determine the chain depth of the error like the command line s_client? Any example code would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer in "Network Security with OpenSSL" by Chandra, Messier and Viega.

It uses SSL_CTX_set_verify to designate a callback function that gets run after the verification routine for each certificate in the chain.

```
SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx, SSL_VERIFY_PEER, verify_callback);


int verify_callback(int ok, X509_STORE_CTX * store)
{
  if (!ok) //if this particular cert had an error
  {
    int depth = X509_STORE_CTX_get_error_depth(store);
    int err = X509_STORE_CTX_get_error(store);
  }
}
```